# La etiqueta a no funciona como link

Tags: javascript, html5

Tengo problemas con esta etiqueta `a`, hace dos días funcionaba perfectamente y abría la modal, pero después de hacer unos cambios en la maquetación ha dejado de funcionar

HTML link y modal:

```
<div id="proyecto1" class="divGaleria">
    <h3>Proyecto 1</h3>
    <a id="abrirModal1" href="#slide4">
        <img class="imgGaleria" src="./media/pics/serietulia.png" alt="">
    </a>
</div>

<div id="modal1">
    <div id="modal1Contenido">
      <img src="./media/pics/serietulia1.jpg" alt="">
      <img src="./media/pics/serietulia2.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
</div>
```

Dejo el js también por si el error esta aquí:

```
var modal1 = document.getElementById("modal1");
var abrirModal1 = document.getElementById("abrirModal1");
// var cerrarModal = document.getElementById ("cerrarModal");

abrirModal1.onclick = function () {
  modal1.style.display = "block";
}
// cerrarModal.onclick = function(){
//     modal1.style.display = "none"
// }
window.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  if (e.target == modal1) {
    modal1.style.display = "none"
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

He simplificado tu código para que veas lo que pasa

```js
var abrirModal1 = document.getElementById("abrirModal1");

abrirModal1.onclick = function () {
  console.log("abrirModal1");
}

window.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  console.log("cerrarModal");
});
```

```html
<div id="proyecto1" class="divGaleria">
    <a id="abrirModal1" href="#slide4">Probar</a>
</div>
```

Básicamente abres y cierra el modal, esto pasa porque a todo `window` le has añadido que para el evento `click` cierre el modal.

Puedes hacer que solo dando click en el modal se cierre:

```
modal1.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  if (e.target == modal1) {
    modal1.style.display = "none"
  }
}
```

o en algún botón "cerrar":

```
cerrarModal.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  if (e.target == modal1) {
    modal1.style.display = "none"
  }
}
```

Comment: El problema es que antes funcionaba, tenia un botón para cerrar y con el window me cerraba al clicar fuera del modal. Entonces no se si al eliminar el botón de cerrar haya hecho que deje de funcionar el resto

Comment: @Marc No te puedo responder porque antes funcionaba y ahora no. Pero el problema que tienes es el que te indico en mi respuesta